# Solution of constrained optimization problem (ADMM)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the following optimization problem which appear in [ADMM](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) page 57.

[image]

Here $\bar{a}$ is avg of $a$. I don't see how eq. 7.13 came? Lagrangian does not seem to bring that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you can offer how you approached the solution. The Lagrangian should have worked fine.

Comment: And looking at your previous work here, it's clear that you're sufficiently proficient in LaTeX that we can ask you to type out your question instead of pasting in an image, which prevents it from being edited/copied/etc.

Comment: @MichaelGrant. Thanks for suggestion. Solving Lagrangian gives me $z_i-a_i=\lambda/N\rho$.

Comment: Ok, but that is not the end, you must eliminate $\lambda$

Comment: Yeah. Actually, I could not figure out how to eliminate $\lambda$. Looking at the sol below, I found that I have to avg. in order to get rid of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\bar{z}$ is fixed, the above problem is minimizing a quadratic function $f$ with a single affine constraint. In general, the optimality condition tells us that the gradient of $f$ at the optimal solution is orthogonal to the null space of the affine constraint (or equivalent,lies in the image of the dual of that affine map).
Now the gradient of the quadratic function is $\rho(z_1-a_1,...,z_N-a_N)$. The affine constraints is $Az=N\bar{z}$, where $A$ is a linear map, $A: \mathbb{R}^{N\times n}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $A(z)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}z_i$. Hence, the dual of $A$ is $A^*: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{N\times n}$, given by $A^*(y)=(y,y,...y)$, $N$ copies of $y$. Hence, the optimality condition says that there exists $y$ such that $z_i-a_i=y$ for $i=1...N$. Taking the average of $N$ equations, we have that $\bar{z}-\bar{a}=y$, and $z_i=a_i+\bar{z}-\bar{a}$ by substitution.